# How to make 3D model fully distributable

Tags: 3d-view

this is not a fully related Blender question but I figured this might be the right place to ask.

I would like to create a standalone distributable 3D model. That is, a file that I can send and that the recipient can open and visualize without the need of installing anything.

Is there any way to do this? Currently I export the model into VRLM and then I can use Cortona 3D to open it with a browse. That still needs a plugin to be installed and I would like to avoid that by compiling everything into a single executable file.

Thank!

Lore

Answer (score 1):

This could depend on how you expect people to see and interact with your model, and how simple the process you wish to be but come to mind:

- making it a distributable "blender game" (an interactive environment), but requires skills, experience and does not support all cycles features, eg. Your recipient could download it and "play it" locally.
  see:
- http://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/licensing.html#standalone-games
- http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/FAQ/Game_Engine/Standalone_game
- using services like https://www.blend4web.com/en/ which require no plugins (is even gpl so you can even host your own)... Your recipient could just visit a page and interact in the browser with the model. (examples: https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/)
- another similar service (but not gpl, afaik) is https://sketchfab.com/

Comment: I only want to add that in case of Blend4Web a Blender scene can be exported even as a standalone web page which can be opened with a standard browser.